# Headset balancing sound

Tags: guitar, drums, midi, sound

I am trying to create a short song but everytime i plugin in my USB headset
it is balancing sound so the guitars sound goes up and down in volume everytime
the basdrum kicks in or snare,

I am using the Arachnid Cirurina headset with MAGIX Music Maker 2013 with MIDI.

How can i fix this problem ?

[Arachnid Circurina](http://www.teknikmagasinet.se/produkter/dator-o-tv-spel/headsets/gaming/arachnid-cicurina) (Warning it's in Swedish)

Comment: It sounds like you have an expander switchied on, or possibly a compressor. Do the guitars get quieter or louder when the bass drum strikes ?

Comment: Sounds like a compressor. Are you familiar with those ? They 'squash'  the signal toward an ideal volume, so if you have something low/middle signal playing (like a guitar), it brings it up in volume. Then, when something with lots of signal like a bass drum plays, that causes the compressor to reduce the volume to compensate, and the other stuff ducks with it. Check the effects on playback software for a compressor. normally they're desirable in that they smooth the sound out, but sounds like yours is a bit too savage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it caused by compressor. Try to find option for adding or remove effect in MAGIX Music Maker 2013. You should turn off the compressor.